# Drop down values open up different mini windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to have a drop down on a form and when the user selects one of the values a pop up to open? What I am trying to do is have a drop down of about probably 125. When the user selects one its going to pop up a mini window showing a picture and the price.. each value will be a different popup? Has anyone ever tried anything like this? Once they select the check mark it will close or they can hit the X on top if they did not like it. Where do I go from here? Any examples would be greatly appreciated!

```
<select name="SPECIAL" id="SPECIAL" >
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as ColdFusion? Nothing ColdFusion related in the code sample provided.

Comment: ColdFusion is server side and cannot control what happens on the client in regards to opening 'mini-windows'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want some thing like this: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/wgqmm8pj/)?

```
$(function() {
    $('#SPECIAL').on('change', function() {
        if ($('option:selected', this).is('[data-img]')) {
            $('#modal_special').find('.modal-body').html('<p>Image will go here:</p>')
            .append('<img alt="coming soon" src="' + $('option:selected', this).data('img') + '"/>')
            .end().modal('show');
        }
    });
    $('.accept').on('click',function() {
        //do something
        $('#modal_special').modal('hide');
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, you do have to include bootstrap for this to work. You can view the source of this for more details: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/wgqmm8pj/show/

Comment: You can use these links as they are in your page: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"><script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` But be sure you have jQuery core included before these lines.

Comment: Sure there's  ... https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v3.2.0/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist.zip

Comment: Yap ..... change `$(this).data('img')` to ... `$('option:selected', this).data('img')` and that should do it: http://jsfiddle.net/wgqmm8pj/1/

Comment: *Exact example*? Mmmmmm.. Can you share your example in a jsfiddle.

Comment: The paths to the images are incorrect. If you are having too much trouble using relative paths, use absolute paths to the images. Be sure you can load the images with the paths you are using. **PRICE**: Use a `data-price` attribute in each `option` element and retrieve it as we're retrieving the images ... `data('price')`.

Comment: See how your exact code loads an image with the `value=1` here: http://jsfiddle.net/kL6fjsfs/3/

Answer (score 2):

Just as very simplified example, [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oomum4qp/)

```
$("#SPECIAL").change(function () {
  $("div.info").hide();
  $("#win" + $(this).val()).show();
});
$(".close").click(function () {
  $(this).parent("div").hide();
});
```

displaying divs with class "info" containing divs with class "close" containing an "X".

Comment: Are you sure you want attach this to all select tags? Wouldn't id be better?

Comment: @JamesAMohler Thanks for your concerns. Sure, id is better, just adjusted answer + fiddle. As it was only a simple example with only one select tag, it didn't matter but of course you're right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery ui to open a dialog window([jquery-ui](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#entry-examples)) and trigger on your select change event like:

```
$("SPECIAL").on("change", function(){
    //here goes the code to open dialog
});
```